# What is the air gap area?

Tags: transformer, electrical, power-engineering

[image]

I found in a book the air gap area is \$Ag= (W+l_g)*(d+l_g)\$  However, I know therectangular prism is \$A=2*(w*d+d*lg+w*lg)\$. Could any one please help me what they  have air gap equals \$Ag= (W+l_g)*(d+l_g)\$

The refereance book for \$ Ag =(W+lg)(d+lg) \$ is Electric Machines and Drive: A First Course.Mohan, Ned

Comment: Can you re-write your equations in [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? Then it will be easier to understand. (On EE we start and end inline Mathjax with `\$` instead of just `$` like on Physics or Math Stackexchange)

Answer (score 2):

What that formula is computing is the approximate effective airgap area, the area that the magnetic flux passes through to complete its circuit round the core.

In the limit of large area pole pieces and small gap, the airgap area is just the area of the poles, W*d. As the lg increases however, this becomes a less good approximation.

The reason we need to know the effective airgap area is that given an H field in the magnetic core, we want to know what the B field will be round the circuit, and how much energy is stored in the airgap (there's negligible energy stored in the core).

Because of the high permeability of the core, its geometry is nicely defined, a length, an area. However, for the airgap, things are trickier. While W*d accounts for the field directly between the poles, it doesn't account for the fringing field that spreads out a little from the area directly between them. This can be computed exactly for a few nicely symmetrical cases by doing a nasty 3D integration, but in general, cannot be determined exactly.

A reasonable approximation to the correct result is to inflate the pole area a little by the length of the gap, giving the formula (W+lg).(d+lg).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer:

> I found in a book the air gap area is \$Ag= (W+l_g)*(d+l_g)\$
>   However, I know the rectangular prism is \$A=2*(w*d+d*lg+w*lg)\$.

Your equation of the rectangular prism  describes the surface area of **all** its faces.

For the air gap only the area through which the magnetic flux lines go matters.
In a simple approach, this is the area w * d.

However, the flux lines don't cross the air gap in a straight line, but bulge somewhat outward as shown in the picture below.
[image]

This fringing flux is visible at the left and right in the picture, but not drawn in the front and back (as those lines will leave the paper/computer screen).
To compensate for the fringing flux in both directions, the width \$w\$ as well as the the depth \$d\$ of the air gap area is extended with \$l_g\$, so \$A_g= (w+l_g)*(d+l_g)\$